# Scrolling from Chrome content script

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm calling `window.scrollBy(0, window.innerHeight)` in a Chrome content script, from a mouse registered `wheel` handler. This is meant to scroll the page by its page height (same effect as PageDown key), but I notice that Chrome immediately undoes the scroll. The net effect is  only a page flicker, due to the programmed scroll and and its immediate undo.

Not surprisingly, if I execute that function from the page console window, it works as expected.

Weirdly, if I call that from a `setTimeout`, the scroll works as expected. The magic timeout I discovered by binary search as 175ms--anything less than that, the scroll is undone. I tried using Promise, too, but it's the same. I wonder why this is.

FWIW, this works without any `setTimeout` hoops on Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was due to the handler having been registered as [passive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Registering the handler with `{passive: false}` got the scroll working as intended. More info [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/passive-event-listeners).